# Opening a modal dialog upon success of ajax post in another modal MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Iam stuck in mvc modal dialogs, I want to open another modal dialog when i click a button inside a modal dialog,which executes ajax to post data to an action that renders the new dialog, the problem is that the call is sent to the action but it never renders the dialog box is there another way to do this 
Some code:

```
    function LoadRightsDialog() {
    //$("#form0").close();


    var list = [];
    var elems = document.getElementById('destiny').children;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].toString() == "[object HTMLDivElement]") {
            list.push(elems[i].id);

        }

    }
    //alert(list.length)
    var json = JSON.stringify(list)
    //$.post("/DistributionList/SaveMyData/", { jsonData: jlst }
    var templateId = '<%:TempData["projectID"]%>';

    //alert(templateId)
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Temp/AddUserDialogSave",
        data: {
            jsonUser: json,
            templateId: templateId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = data;
           // alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
  }
```

the event that calls this function

```
<img src="~/Content/saveDialog.png" class="box" id="box" onclick="LoadRightsDialog()" />
```

and the controller action

```
public ActionResult AddRightsDialog(string jsonUser,string templateId){
return PartialView();//this loads the modal dialog 

 }
```

Comment: Does the line: return alert(data.Result) actually alert the correct HTML?

Comment: it doesn't alert any thing

Comment: You should use Console.log(data.Result) anyway - it's easier to read the output. If you're not even getting any output it's hard to answer the question without seeing more of what you're doing.

Comment: ok i have added some more code kindly see that, the modal dialog however is not loading

Comment: Can you try changing alert(data.Result); to console.log(data); and check developer tools console (Chrome F12 > Console). Does that output anything?

Comment: I suspect that the problem might lie with the line `url: "/Temp/AddUserDialogSave"`, but you don't provide routing information so can't be sure. Also, the action returns a partial view which basically renders html, but your ajax call expects `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @elolos can you suggest a soln

Answer (score 0):

The partial view returned by the action should return a string containing the view's html and not JSON. Furthermore, the url should contain the correct action method name.

Assuming the controller name is `TempController` and the route that matches is the default, you need to edit the url and datatype parts your ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Temp/AddRightsDialog",
        data: {
            jsonUser: json,
            templateId: templateId
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = data;
           // alert(data.Result);
        },
        traditional: true
    });
```